# Stop language changes in app after locale changes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use a runtime permission library called [Kpermission](https://github.com/fondesa/kpermissions) to request permission, but the issue is the permission request follows device language and not  app language

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible for a permission dialog to not appear in the device's set language. You don't get to control that because it is part of the OS and a security feature.

Comment: It is possible that Android 13's app-specific language support could extend to system dialogs like this. However, I have not tried that. Otherwise, I agree with Tenfour04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Instead of changing better you display your custom dialog before requesting permission to explain you the purpose of permission

You can check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Note: Your app cannot customize the dialog that appears when you call launch(). To provide more information or context to the user, change your app's UI so that it's easier for users to understand why a feature in your app needs a particular permission. For example, you might change the text in the button that enables the feature.
>
> Also, the text in the system permission dialog references the permission group associated with the permission that you requested. This permission grouping is designed for system ease-of-use, and your app shouldn't rely on permissions being within or outside of a specific permission group.

[Example Custom Dialog Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTiU.png)

Comment: Thank you  for responding to my question Frans Hidayat